# SharePoint not authenticated after disable SMBv1 on domain controller

Tags: sharepoint-server

After disabling SMBv1 on domain controller SharePoint is not accessible, is there any configuration required on SharePoint farm.

Comment: Please provide more information: How was SMBv1 disabled? What kind of error do you get on your SharePoint Site? Can you provide a ULS-Log of the error?

Comment: We are getting ready to implement the same change.  SMBv1 is to be disabled per Policy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your reply, actually there was some issue on AD domain controller.

Now they fixed and SharePoint is working. Thanks for your help